# JAVA - The calendar invite doesn't add to attendee calendar?

Tags: java, ical4j

Here is my .ics file. I'm using ical4j to implement the calendar functionality. However, the calendar invite doesn't add to attendee's calendar. What's missing? Any advice appreciated.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Events Calendar//iCal4j 1.0//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20200226T030652Z
DTSTART:20200226T114100Z
DTEND:20200226T124100Z
SUMMARY:Tips session
METHOD:PUBLISH
TZID:Australia/Sydney
UID:e90c7cdf-7c92-43a6-b132-cfcfec9c328e
ORGANIZER;ROLE=CHAIR;CN=Example Team:mailto:team@example.net
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED:mailto:test@gmail.com
LOCATION:test location
STATUS:CONFIRMED
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the iCalendar iTiP spec (rfc5546) you'll see the "PUBLISH" method is not meant for creating meetings with attendees:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5546#section-3.2.1

Instead you probably want to be using the "REQUEST" method to invite attendees to your event:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5546#section-3.2.2

Comment: Ical4j also has a user agent implementation to make publishing calendars easier. You may want to look at: http://ical4j.github.io/docs/ical4j/api/3.0.4/net/fortuna/ical4j/agent/VEventUserAgent.html

Comment: Also see: http://ical4j.github.io/2018/02/26/calendar-user-agent.html for more info